# Elasticsearch on Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Does anyone has successfully ran **Elasticsearch on Docker for Windows**? Haven't found any information for this combination.

I've had insufficient memory issues with microsoft/windowsservercore image at boot time, although with microsoft/nanoserver at least it's possible to boot, not yet tested under load.

Also, there's some funky problems with using volume mounts where elaticsearch throw exception: "**Unable to access 'path.data'**", although the mount is perfectly writable from shell inside container:

```
docker volume create log

docker run --rm -it -p 15000:15000 -v log:c:/log/elasticsearch/data microsoft/windowsservercore powershell
```

or with host binding:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 15000:15000 -v C:/temp/log:c:/log/elasticsearch/data microsoft/windowsservercore powershell
```

And calling:

```
c:/log/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=log_cluster -Enode.name=${HOSTNAME} -Enetwork.host="0.0.0.0" -Ehttp.port=15000
```

I get:

> [2017-04-28T15:40:25,501][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [644FE5A1B514] uncaught
>   exception in thread [main]
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data'
>   (C:\log\elasticsearch\data)
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:58)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data'
>   (C:\log\elasticsearch\data)
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:397)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:208)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:114)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:237)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           ... 6 more Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\log\elasticsearch\data
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getFinalPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:82)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:242)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:836) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:44) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:435)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:395)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:208)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:114)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:237)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
>           ... 6 more

Elasticsearch 5.3.1
Tried with docker version 17.03 and 17.05rc1/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the explanation with a work around [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27537#issuecomment-271546031).

I posted a solution on a question I asked that was identical to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898788/docker-volume-access-error)

Additionally I published a Dockerfile that includes the workaround on Github:  https://github.com/SharpSeeEr/Dockerfiles

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly specifying a larger amount of memory with one of the [memory options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints)?